# Updating remote user's locally installed intranet source

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, networking

We have remote users who are in and out of connection. They have local databases as well as locally hosted versions of our intranet. From here they fill out workorders. The workorders go into a directory that will eventually be automatically synced over vpn when they enter connection again. We have already put in place a system for making database changes.

What we are trying to accomplish now is come up with a way to update the actual local webpages in a similar syncing manner. Initially we were thinking of using GIT and using the local machine web directory as a repo. Then when changes were made we could issue a script that would update their live folders to what our production repo says. What other ways could we accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Version control may be your best option. But other methods are Robocopy for windows, or rysnc for linux.

Comment: Suppose that a laptop has been out of range for months - would robo copy be able to update in a manner similar to git?

Comment: Robocopy will be able to sync up the directoties? Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy for more details.